# How to cout a constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-keyword

I'm kinda new to C++ and i got this problem while learning about it

So I have created this class

```
class A {
    int num;
public:
    //constructor
    A(int num) {
        this->num = num;
    }
    int getNum() {
        return num;
    }
    //overload <<
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os,A& a) {
        os << a.getNum();
        return os;
    }
};
```

In the main function, if I use `cout<< A(1);` it compiles wrong ( code C2679 in Visual Studio 2017 ).
How can I make it like `cout<< int(1);` ? Do I need to overload any other operator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your overload needs to take a `const A&`, otherwise the *anonymous temporary* `A(1)` cannot bind to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did it

Answer (score 1):

One more way is to overload the `operator <<` with  `rvalue references`

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, A&& a) {        
        os << a.getNum();
        return os;
    }
```